# Overflow prob in css

Tags: html, css

While i was making a website i had a problem of text overflow.

This is the code

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
 <div>sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
```

The `ssssss` is overflowing in the div i want them on the next line without typing `<br>`.

I dont know how to apply  `display: flex;`.
Please give me some code for making the `sss` only stand inside the `div`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`word-break: break-all;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</div>
```

Comment: @Advaith, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 3):

Use `word-break: break-all` property

```
div {
      width: 100px;
      background: blue;
      word-break: break-all
  
    }
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c8ne7uz/)

Comment: Thank you very much bro.